# How can I find the neighbours of countries in a list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list

I'm programming the game Risk in c++. In that game you can declare war to the countries that border on your country.

*But the only way I could figure out to test if two countries are "neighbours" is a giant if test.*

Here is the declaration of the list:

```
//Europe:
gebieden << CGebied("iceland","europe");
gebieden << CGebied("scandinavia","europe");
gebieden << CGebied("great-britain", "europe");
gebieden << CGebied("northern-europe","europe");
gebieden << CGebied("western-europe","europe");
gebieden << CGebied("southern-europe","europe");
gebieden << CGebied("ukraine", "europe");
//Asia
gebieden << CGebied("ural", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("siberia", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("yakutsk", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("kamchatka", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("irkutsk", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("mongolia", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("afghanistan", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("china", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("japan", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("middle-east", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("india", "asia");
gebieden << CGebied("siam", "asia");
//Australië
gebieden << CGebied("indonesia", "australia");
gebieden << CGebied("new-guinea", "australia");
gebieden << CGebied("western-australia", "australia");
gebieden << CGebied("eastern-australia", "australia");
//Africa
gebieden << CGebied("egypt", "africa");
gebieden << CGebied("north-africa", "africa");
gebieden << CGebied("east-africa", "africa");
gebieden << CGebied("congo", "africa");
gebieden << CGebied("south-africa", "africa");
gebieden << CGebied("madagascar", "africa");
//North-America
gebieden << CGebied("alaska","n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("northwest territory", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("alberta", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("ontario", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("quebec", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("greenland", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("western-us", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("eastern-us", "n-america");
gebieden << CGebied("central-america", "n-america");
//South-America
gebieden << CGebied("venezuela", "s-america");
gebieden << CGebied("brazil", "s-america");
gebieden << CGebied("peru", "s-america");
gebieden << CGebied("argentina", "s-america");
```

Here is a part of the giant if test:

```
if(QString::compare(naam1,"alaska",Qt::CaseInsensitive) || QString::compare(naam2,"alaska", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
{
    if(QString::compare(naam1,"kamchatka", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || QString::compare(naam2,"kamchatka", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        return 1;
    if(QString::compare(naam1, "northwest territory", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || QString::compare(naam2, "northwest territory", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        return 1;
    if(QString::compare(naam1, "alberta", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || QString::compare(naam2, "alberta", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        return 1;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?
Thanks!

Comment: Create a `map` of neighbours.

Comment: Your question is: "Hey, I have a list of countries that I'm storing, presumably in some structure that I will not explain, and my existing test for bordering countries is very inefficient, in some way which I also will not explain, but I want someone to tell me how to make it more efficient, without me showing the actual inefficient code, except to vaguely describe it as a "giant if test"; so everyone will have to use their magical mind ray-beam machines in order to look at the code in my head, and tell me how to make it better". Is that an accurate description of your question?

Comment: yeah that's pretty accurate, i'll upload my code :)

Comment: There is Ukraine in the list, but no Russia. Russia is divided into pieces. Are you a kind of clairvoyant by any chance?

Comment: I used a map i found on the internet ;)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of datastructure do you use to store your courtries in?

I would suggest a graph type structure: for every country you keep a list (`std::set<Country*>`) of neighbours. This way you can easily check if another country is in it's list of neighbours.

another possibility is this:

```
bool isNeighbour[COUNTRY_COUNT][COUNTRY_COUNT];
```

this is more `c` than `c++`. It assumes that your counties are numbered, and enables you to look up *neighbourness* like

```
if(isNeighbour[countryAid][countryBid]){...
```

remember though that you'll have to fill in each relation twice to make them mutual.

Comment: Well, string comparison is relatively a lot of work. You can try to lookup your country by id. If you store them in a `QSet<Country>` looking up a country will take only `O(log(n))` time. (i don't know the type of `gebieden`, but then you can do `gebieden["alaska"].isNeighbour(gebieden["birma"])` if you implement `CGebied::isNeighbour`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using a giant 'if' would not be the right way to follow.

I would try to create a `class Map`, and inside of that class I would use the name of each country as a function that already have the informations that I need, in this case it is the neighbours.

Doing this, whenever I want to discover which countries are the neighbours I just need to call the `class Map` with the function of that country, like `country.Italy(neighbours)` or just `country.Italy()` , where country would be an object and Italy the name of the function inside of the class Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vector of pointers within each countries structure to create a "flowchart" like reference to all countries that said country neighbours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct country{
    vector<country*> neighbours;
    //various other properties of the country.
    string name;
};

int main()
{
    country country1;
    country country2;
    country1.name = "The first country";
    country2.name = "The second country";
    //Make country1 and country 2 neighbours.
    country1.neighbours.push_back(&country2);
    country2.neighbours.push_back(&country1);

    cout<<country1.name<<" is a neighbour with "<<country1.neighbours[0]->name<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```